# Setting AWS S3 storage class for object uploaded with Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use this code to upload files to S3:

```rb
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(...)
obj = s3.bucket(s3_bucket).object("final/path")
success = obj.upload_file('my/local/file')
```

How can I change the storage class to *Standard-Infrequent Access*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass `storage_class` option to `#upload_file`:

```rb
success = obj.upload_file('my/local/file', storage_class: "STANDARD_IA")
```

Comment: Where have you found that? From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#upload_file-instance_method) it seems that there is no such option for `upload_file` (it only lists `multipart_threshold ` and `thread_count ` as the options)

Comment: These two options are used directly in `#upload_file`, the rest ones - in the base code called from `#upload_file`.